# Adding a set value to a cell with a macro

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a value, which can be changed manually, but I want a button which I can click to add a value of 200 to that number. This might be a stupid question but I've been trying all afternoon. I don't want to change the formula of the cell, I just want it as a static value so I can do manual changes to that number not using the button I will assign this script to.

Comment: Do you have an example script you were trying to adapt to your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script does what I needed:

```
function RSNW() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AS42').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AS42').getValue() + 250);
};
```

It adds 250 to the value I have in AS42.